# Getting 'TypeError: interpolate is not a function' in React-Native 0.68

Tags: react-native

I create latest react native 0.68 project and using react navigation 5, I am using react-native-reanimated 2.2.4
project build successfully but when I use drawer navigation
getting error

Here is the package json

```
{
  "name": "NassauTennisApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.17.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.17.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`interpolate()` was renamed to `interpolateNode()` in Reanimated 2. You can downgrade to `react-native-reanimated@1.13.1` to solve the issue